# Find() does not return result with cache

Tags: phalcon

I am trying to implement memcache into my application, but I am running into some strange issues. If I run find() when there is no cache, then I get no results found. However, if I run the same query (refresh the page), then I get the results I expect.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    //Set the models cache service
    $di->set('modelsCache', function(){
        // Cache data for one day by default
        $frontCache = new \Phalcon\Cache\Frontend\Data(array(
            "lifetime" => 86400
        ));

        // Memcached connection settings
        $cache = new \Phalcon\Cache\Backend\Memcache($frontCache, array(
            "host" => "localhost",
            "port" => "11211"
        ));

        return $cache;
    });

<?php
class VideosController extends IndexController {
    public function viewAction() {
        /**
         * This will always return an array;
         * param 0 will always be the int
         */
        $params = $this->dispatcher->getParams();

        $id = $params[0];

        $cacheName = 'videoForView_'.$id;

        try {
            $video = Videos::findFirst(array(
                'id='.$id,
                'cache' => array(
                    'key' => $this->router->getControllerName().'_'.$this->router->getActionName().'_'.$id
                )
            ));

            $this->view->setVar('video', $video);
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            echo '<pre>';
            var_dump($e);
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

I am under the assumption that the Phalcon Model class would return me a database query, if there is no hit in the memcache server. It seems that the find() does find something and caches it, but it does not return me anything. Am I not understanding how the caching works in Phalcon? Or am I just doing something wrong?

Comment: what version of phalcon are you using?

Comment: I was originally using 0.7, but I'm up to 0.8. Both of those versions gave me the same results.

Comment: can you test with 0.8.0b1? it was released yesterday

Comment: I just did a pull, and it seems like I got 0.8.0a2; recompiled and everything. I am still getting the same results. I did phpversion('phalcon') and got 0.8.0. I don't know if it did not take, but I would be surprised. Either way, still got the same results :|

Comment: can you print echo Phalcon\Version::get()? Also install the extension with sudo ./install safe

Comment: 0.8.0 BETA 1. That's probably what I needed to run initially :). Thanks for that. [Edit] Probably came off as if it helped. I am still seeing the issue. I'm gonna take this over to the group on Google. See if they can help. Thanks, again, twistedextra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved. I worked with Andres (one of the developers of Phalcon), helping him resolve the issues I was having. Turns out it was deeper in the code than I would've expected.

The good news is it's resolved, and pushed up to the 0.8.0 branch on [phalcon's github](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/tree/0.8.0)! Don't forget to recompile!